# Postgresql - remove unwanted characters from data stream using stored procedure or triggers?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a data stream coming from a machine and this is stored in a Postgresql  DB. I need to strip out various unwanted characters and keep both the original result and the new result. eg I have data "34.5 !*" or "17.9 P-" in a field and want to store "34.5" or "17.9" . I was wondering about using a trigger to call a procedure to write the data minus the unwanted characters to a new field...

Comment: Are you sure that should be done on the DB side? This clean-up should be done BEFORE it reaches the database

Comment: If there are multiple clients it is better to take care of data integrity in the DB. Or redundant on both sides if it is important.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that in a trigger with a regular expression, something like:

```
create or replace function clean_value() 
returns trigger 
language plpgsql
AS
$body$
begin
   new.clean_column = regexp_replace(new.dirty_column, '[^0-9\.]', '', 'g');
   return new;
end;
$body$
/
```

That will store a "clean" version of the input `dirty_column` into the column `clean_column`.